# DVD drive thrashing on Wii

Tags: nintendo-wii

My kids just started playing the old Ben 10 Wii game (the one before Alien Force), and while they (and I) really like it, I can't get over the fact that this particular title thrashes the DVD drive like no other.  It is literally seeking the entire time the game is being played.  Surely, this can't be good for the system, but maybe the parts are intended to survive such a beating.

Has anyone ever read about documented cases where the game design (constant seeking instead of more caching, perhaps) has actually contributed to the early failure of a system?

Comment: Silly question, but I may as well ask: This behavior is specific to this one game, yes?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer 6: Yes -- "this particular title thrashes the DVD drive like no other".  :)

Comment: We've had two DVD drives fail on our Wii with the same "thrashing" symptoms, but that was on all games rather than just the one. I'd double check that the disk is clean and keep an eye on the situation to check if it spreads to other disks. Both times Nintendo replaced the drive free of charge.

Comment: get Dolphin and play on your PC. problem solved!

Comment: I think this is normal for DKCR.

Answer (score 2):

I've played two games where I noticed the DVD drive thrashing during gameplay: *Rayman Raving Rabbids* and *Donkey Kong Country Returns*.  It would usually happen for a few minutes then stop and only happen when expected (i.e., during transitions).

A couple ideas:

- Make sure you've got the latest software update.
- Try playing the game on someone else's Wii.  If happens on another console, you'll know it is the game.  If it doesn't happen, you'll know your Wii is unhappy.

If you end up sending your console into Nintendo, make sure you backup all your game data onto an SD card.